# Filter in tkinter for a treeview based on a dataframe for pandas not working as intended

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter, filter, treeview

So, here is my problem:

I builded a dataframe with stock data **dfAcciones**. Y add the data to a treeview variable called **tabla**:

In order to do this, i have a function that cleans the dataframe and another one that shows the dataframe info with a button:

```
        def limpiar_dataframe():

            for item in tabla.get_children():
                tabla.delete(item)

        def datos_excel():

            limpiar_dataframe()

            tabla['column'] = list(dfAcciones.columns)
            tabla['show'] = "headings"
            for columna in tabla['column']:
                tabla.heading(columna, text=columna)
                df_fila = dfAcciones.to_numpy().tolist()
            for fila in df_fila:
                tabla.insert('', 'end', values = fila)

        tabla = ttk.Treeview(main_window_acciones, height=15)
        tabla.place(x=10, y=400, width=800, height=400)
        ladox = Scrollbar(main_window_acciones, orient= HORIZONTAL, command=tabla.xview)
        ladox.place(x=10, y=370, width=800, height=25) 
        ladoy = Scrollbar(main_window_acciones, orient= VERTICAL, command=tabla.yview)
        ladoy.place(x=820, y=400, width=25, height=400) 
        tabla.configure(xscrollcommand=ladox.set, yscrollcommand=ladoy.set)

        botonmostrar = Button(main_window_acciones, text='Mostrar', command=datos_excel)
        botonmostrar.place(x=80, y=340)
```

[Image of how the data is shown in the tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIGTN.png)

Once the data is all shown in the tkinter window, i use the filters above seen in the image such as PEG Ratio, Compnay name and Sector Name. All of the filters work, this is how i build them:

First of all the buttons to filter:

```
        text_nombre = tk.Label(widgets_frame_filtros, text="Nombre empresa: ")
        text_nombre.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")
        name_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame_filtros)
        name_entry.insert(0, "Name")
        name_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda e: name_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
        name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=(0, 5), sticky="ew")

        text_sector = tk.Label(widgets_frame_filtros, text="Escoge PEG Ratio: ")
        text_sector.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")
        peg_ratio_spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(widgets_frame_filtros, from_=0, to=250, increment=.1)
        peg_ratio_spinbox.insert(0, "0")
        peg_ratio_spinbox.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky = "ew")

        text_sector = tk.Label(widgets_frame_filtros, text="Escoge Sector: ")
        text_sector.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")
        sectorname_list = ["All", "Atención sanitaria", "Bienes raíces", "Energía", "Industria", "Materiales básicos","Productos de consumo cíclicos", "Productos de consumo defensivos", "Servicios de comunicaciones", "Servicios financieros", "Servicios públicos", "Tecnología"]
        sector_name_combobox = ttk.Combobox(widgets_frame_filtros, values=sectorname_list)
        sector_name_combobox.current(0)
        sector_name_combobox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ew")
```

Second i have a button that once the filter is set "updates" the table:

```
        botonrefresh = Button(main_window_acciones, text='Actualizar', command=actualiza_ventana)
        botonrefresh.place(x=750, y=340)
```

Third, once the button to "update" the table is used, we proceed to filter the information:

```
def actualiza_ventana():

            limpiar_dataframe()

            name = name_entry.get()
            peg_ratio = float(peg_ratio_spinbox.get())
            sector_name = sector_name_combobox.get()

            dfAcciones1 = pd.DataFrame()
            dfAcciones2 = pd.DataFrame()
            dfAcciones3 = pd.DataFrame()

            if sector_name != 'All':
                dfAcciones1=dfAcciones.query("SectorName==@sector_name")
                sector_name_combobox.set(sectorname_list[0])
                
                tabla['column'] = list(dfAcciones1.columns)
                tabla['show'] = "headings"
                for columna in tabla['column']:
                    tabla.heading(columna, text=columna)
                    df_fila = dfAcciones1.to_numpy().tolist()
                for fila in df_fila:
                    tabla.insert('', 'end', values = fila)


            if name != 'Name':
                dfAcciones2 = dfAcciones[dfAcciones['Name'].str.contains(name)]
                name_entry.delete(0, "end")
                name_entry.insert(0, "Name")

                tabla['column'] = list(dfAcciones2.columns)
                tabla['show'] = "headings"
                for columna in tabla['column']:
                    tabla.heading(columna, text=columna)
                    df_fila = dfAcciones2.to_numpy().tolist()
                for fila in df_fila:
                    tabla.insert('', 'end', values = fila)
        

                    
            if peg_ratio != "0":
                dfAcciones3 = dfAcciones.query("PEGRatio >= @peg_ratio")
                peg_ratio_spinbox.delete(0, "end")
                peg_ratio_spinbox.insert(0, "0")

                tabla['column'] = list(dfAcciones3.columns)
                tabla['show'] = "headings"
                for columna in tabla['column']:
                    tabla.heading(columna, text=columna)
                    df_fila = dfAcciones3.to_numpy().tolist()
                for fila in df_fila:
                    tabla.insert('', 'end', values = fila)
```

The problem comes once the dataframe is filtered, while i filter peg_ratio, the treeview is filtered correctly and is shown as expected:
[Image of peg_ratio filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVi99.png)

However, when i filter either by company name or sector, the filter dosn't work as expected and shows the filtered plus the dataframe that was there before:
[Image of company name filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k3Hn.png)

I don't understand what is the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Have you considered using [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable)? Also, it's really hard to step inside your code without a  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Tranbi, the code is to long is around 900 lines, this is just a section with variables. I'm using pandas data frame for managing the data, can pandas data table be used into tkinter treeview?

If yes i will try. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Note that `peg_ratio` is a float number inside `actualiza_ventana()`, so the checking `peg_ratio != "0"` will always be evaluated as True.

Change the checking to `peg_ratio != 0.0` will fix the issue.